# js click event not responding on mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on the mobile menu hamburger button, nothing happens. I'm anticipating that the hamburger menu will change and the mobile menu will display although neither event seems to trigger.

I know that I get into my javascript MobileMenu.js file but the .click() event doesn't seem to be firing as I get no response from the event. I do get a console log with my message "Got into the MobileMenu!" but I don't get the "You clicked it!" message from inside the event. Also, the css doesn't fire either as the hamburger menu doesn't transition to an X.

I'm not getting any errors on the console log or on my gulp build or gulp watch. All of my packages are up-to-date as well. I've been working this for some time now and I need another set of eyes to see what I'm missing.

Thanks!

MobileMenu.js

```
console.log("Got into the MobileMenu!");

class MobileMenu{
    constructor() {
        this.menuIcon = $(".site-header__menu-icon");
        this.siteHeader = $(".site-header__nav");
        this.menuContent = $(".site-header__btn-container");
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        this.menuIcon.click(this.toggleTheMenu).bind(this);
    }

    toggleTheMenu() {
        console.log("You clicked it!");
        this.siteHeader.toggleClass("site-header--is-expanded");
        this.menuContent.toggleClass("site-header__menu-content--is-visible");
        this.btnContent.toggleClass("site-header__btn-container--is-visible");
    }
} 

export default MobileMenu;
```

HTML

```
    <div class="site-header__menu-icon">
      <div class="site-header__menu-icon__middle"></div>
    </div>

    <ul class="site-header__logo" role="navigation">
      <li class=""><a href="/"><h2>Logo name</h2></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="site-header__nav">
      <li class="site-header__nav--item"><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
      <li class="site-header__nav--item"><a href="#what">What I Do</a></li>
      <li class="site-header__nav--item"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="site-header__btn-container">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn__nav btn--orange open-modal">Get in Touch</a>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </header>
```

CSS - some

```
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: 'Aclonica', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

    &--is-expanded {
        background-color: rgba($mainBlue, .55);
    }

    @mixin atMedium {
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
        height: 65px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        background-color: rgba($mainBlue, .9);
        transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
        list-style: none;
        color: #fff;

        &--dark {
            background-color: rgba(23, 51, 72, .85);
        }

    }
```

I'm anticipating that when the menu button is clicked, the mobile menu will become visible and the menu content will populate.

Comment: where have you instantiated the class MobileMenu?

Comment: it may be that because you are setting variables in the constructor, they don't yet exist in the DOM. So they can't be found by jQuery

Comment: Could you create a Codepen or Fiddle and provide a [mre]? Otherwise you might not get much feedback if users have to guess what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Answer. Found out the problem wasn't with the code but with the build process. The scripts weren't being compiled properly. Thanks for the suggestions though.